# Best away to distinct a list of objects by two fields equals with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, distinct

I have some duplicated records in my database with different Ids, like:

```
id      | title         | date              |flag |  
--------+---------------+-------------------+-----+
    2099|Test           |2022-11-29 00:00:00| 1   |
    2100|Test           |2022-11-29 00:00:00| 1   |
    2101|Test           |2022-11-29 00:00:00| 1   |
    2102|Test           |2022-11-29 00:00:00| 1   |
```

and this is the code to get all records from my database:

```
event_get = Event.query.filter(Event.flag == 1)
result = events_schema.dump(event_get)
data = dict(event=result)
```

I wanna distinct the results by title and date, so as the example with four records, I would have all of them with the same title and date, returning only one record

I did not find a way of do this with sqlalchemy, is It possible or I would need to use a alternative code in the returned list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the columns to `distinct()` to generate [distinct on](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.distinct.params.*expr) like this:

```py
events = session.query(Event).distinct(Event.title, Event.date).filter(Event.flag == 1).all()
```

This uses a subquery that finds the smallest id for each group of title/date.  The main query then only returns events with ids in that subquery.  I guess check and see if this works in mysql.  My small test seems to work.

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, func
subq = select(func.min(Event.id)).group_by(Event.title, Event.date)
events = session.query(Event).where(Event.id.in_(subq)).all()
```

Also if you just need those exact values you can probably just use regular `DISTINCT` like this:

```py
for (title, date) in session.query(Event.title, Event.date).distinct().all():
    print (title, date)
```

Comment: It seems to work, but I`m using a MySql database as well, who does not support distinct on. Is there another solution?

Comment: @Possenti I added some alternatives that might work.  I don't have mysql available right now so better test them and see if they return the results you want.